# How to list all the docker image layers on a host?

Tags: docker

Yes, just as the title said. Or, is there a command to do this?

And it will be better if we can list the size along with that layers, like

```
$ do some magic here
$ f54710e9952f065c3dbf6c282d7e2c3eaf54f30734bdaf4f91e07e8330432729 10 Mb
$ 9ad2648b7ae01c151e9336203362abadb97dfe7cfb55f138d16baba96691fe85 10 Mb
$ 1a895dd3954aede5ea9e6bc23d23e8b1f6040df94647d83e71f96d60131d3235 0 Mb
$ 501f51238f9ef52bcb6aecb6e2c1c04b3f8607c855d9b2cf7da780946ce02ec2 120 Mb
```

Answer (score 0):

check `docker history myimage`

the doc

http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/history/

Answer (score 0):

`docker images -a` should list everything